# No muestra el formulario al compilar

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este código de abajo. Solo es un `Form` y un `Label`. Tiene que alterar los colores con el tiempo de `0.05` segundos, en este ejemplo puse `500` ms para ver el cambio. Mientras el `Form` esté de color blanco, `Label` tiene que estar en negro, luego cambia al revés, es decir, el forma de blanco se pone en negro y las letras del `Label` del negro al blanco así por cada cierto tiempo. Nunca muestra el `Form` en pantalla.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Apruebalos_a_todos_cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            while (true)
            {
                cambioColor();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                cambioColor2();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        void cambioColor()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Black; // Formulario negro.
            //this.ForeColor = Color.White; // Cambia textos en blanco.
            label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        void cambioColor2()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White; // Formulario blanco.
            //this.ForeColor = Color.Black; // Cambia textos en negro.
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

¿Qué hago mal?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No. No te lo va a mostrar nunca.

Los eventos de dibujo estan en el mismo thread que los eventos de ejecucion de codigo en tu caso.

Como pusiste todo el codigo en el load, en un bucle infinito, que para colmo tiene un monton de sleeps, lo que esta pasando es que se ejecuta eternamente el load, y nunca llega a dibujar el form.

Para evitar esto, tu funcion de cambio de color, deberia estar en otro metodo aparte del thread, ser controlada por un timer (no por un sleep) y en lo posible, ser una funcion asyncronica (una llamada con await), para que el formulario pueda responder a los cambios que se le piden.

Para hacerlo funcionar, prueba el siguiente codigo.
Agrega a tu form un objeto timer, y pon su intervalo en 500. Tambien, asignale el evento tick, al evento que vas a encontrar mas abajo, agrega un boton para que puedas cortar el programa:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool state = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool b = await CambiarColor();
    }

    private async Task<bool> CambiarColor()
    {
        state = !state;
        if (state)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Black; // Formulario negro.
            label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White; 
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias.

Antes de responder, lo he hecho con dos timer. Sabía que con uno también se puede pero no tengo idea de hacerlo. Mi código es este.

```html
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        void cambioColor()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Black; // Formulario negro.
            //this.ForeColor = Color.White; // Cambia textos en blanco.
            label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        void cambioColor2()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White; // Formulario blanco.
            //this.ForeColor = Color.Black; // Cambia textos en negro.
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            cambioColor();
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Start();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            cambioColor2();
            timer2.Stop();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Desde que ejecute el ejecutable, empieza a cambiar de color fondo y letra, pero no debe tener un botón para detenerse nunca.

Gracias.